# RxJava2 chain commands with optional conditions

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm still trying to figure out reactive programming and am trying to create a chain with RxJava2. The logic is as follows when creating an order (pseudocode).

```
void createOrder {
    R r1 = null, r2 = null, r3 = null;
    Order order = null;
    if (condition1) {
        then r1 = new R();
    } else if (condition2) {
        then r2 = new R();
    }

    if (condition3) {
        then r3 = new R();
    }

    if (r1 not null) {
        if (r3 not null) {
            create order with r1 + r3
        } else {
            create order with r1
        }
    } else if (r2 not null) {
        if (r3 not null) {
            create order with r2 + r3
        } else {
            create order with r2
        }
    } else {
        fail creating an order
    }   
}
```

I have created 4 `Single`s that do the work of creating r1, r2, r3 and the order but I can't figure out how to chain all of these together to make the entire sequence with the above logic.

I think we could use several `Maybe`s for the `if (condition)` checks but am not sure how to chain them together with the `Single`s to achieve the above.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with r1, r2, r3? You need to provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: they are simple Java objects. Basically the if checks are various condition checks based on which the objects r1, r2, r3 are created (as shown above)

Comment: Should the creation of r1, r2, r3 be async?

Comment: they could be but need to all be done before creating the order

Comment: This looks like the FizzBuzz problem but with RxJava. Don't think about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

With some reordering of the logic it isn't that difficult to convert to a reactive chain.

What you need to do is observe what the possible end results are and what the requirements to reach those results are:

1. `r1` or as backup `r2` must have a value
2. if `r3` has a value, merge with the previous result
3. if this value exists, turn into order.

Point 1. can be constructed by considering each variable a `Maybe<R>` object, then using `Maybe.switchIfEmpty` to calculate the value.

Point 2. can be implemented using the second `flatmap` implementation which allows for different reactions based on the result from `r3`.

Point 3. can be done in the flatmap as well, finalizing it with a `Single<Order>` that throws an error if the above steps did not yield a result.

This results in the following pseudo-implementation:

```
Maybe<R> r1 = Maybe.defer(() -> {
    if (condition1)
        return Maybe.just(new R());
    else 
        return Maybe.empty();
});

Maybe<R> r2 = Maybe.defer(() -> {
    if (condition2)
        return Maybe.just(new R());
    else 
        return Maybe.empty();
});

Maybe<R> r3 = Maybe.defer(() -> {
    if (condition3)
        return Maybe.just(new R());
    else 
        return Maybe.empty();
});

return r1.switchIfEmpty(r2).flatMap((r1r2) -> {
    return r3.flatMap(
        (r3val) -> Maybe.just(create order with r1r2 + r3val),
        (err) -> Maybe.error(err),
        () -> Maybe.just(create order with r1r2)
    );
}).switchIfEmpty(Single.defer(() -> {
    return Single.error(fail creating an order);
}));
```

The end result of this code will be `Single<Order>`.